# I want to compare hash that I have passed in the argument of the function but keep getting this error

Tags: solidity, hash-algorithm, data-types

```
function compare(string memory input, uint _y) public returns (uint){ 
  bytes32 hashedinput = keccak256(input);
}
```

> ```
> Error: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string memory to bytes memory requested. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.
>   bytes32 hashedinput = keccak256(input);
>                                   ^---^
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keccak256` takes `bytes` as input, use:

```
bytes32 hashedinput = keccak256(bytes(input));
```

hope it helps.